# Migration from Vaadin 6.8 to Vaadin 7 compile widgetset

Tags: java, gwt, compilation, vaadin

We have a large project that is created using Vaadin 6.8
We recently decided to upgrade to version 7.
Refactor the code that caused it in line with changes in the framework.
There was a problem: we can not compile widgetset ...

The project was created in Netbeans IDE, a compilation produced with Ant script.

Here's a error:

[image: compilation_error]

Here's Ant script:

```
<import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

<target name="widgetset-init">
    <property name="widgetset" value="user_interface.ApplicationWidgetSet"/>
    <property name="widgetset-path" value="user_interface"/>
    <property name="client-side-destination" value="web/VAADIN/widgetsets" />
    <property name="generate.widgetset" value="1"/>
</target>

<target name="generate-widgetset" depends="widgetset-init, compile" if="generate.widgetset">
    <echo>Updating ${widgetset}...</echo>

    <mkdir dir="${src.dir}/${widgetset-path}"/>

    <java classname="com.vaadin.server.widgetsetutils.WidgetSetBuilder" failonerror="yes" fork="yes" maxmemory="512m">
        <arg value="${widgetset}"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Xss1024k"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.awt.headless=true"/>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${src.dir}" />
            <pathelement path="${javac.classpath}" />
            <pathelement path="${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="compile-widgetset" depends="init, widgetset-init, generate-widgetset">
    <echo>Compiling ${widgetset} into ${client-side-destination} directory...</echo>

    <java classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler" failonerror="yes" fork="yes" maxmemory="512m">
        <arg value="-war" />
        <arg value="${client-side-destination}" />
        <arg value="${widgetset}" />
        <jvmarg value="-Xss1024k"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.awt.headless=true"/>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${src.dir}" />
            <pathelement path="${javac.classpath}" />
            <pathelement path="${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: Absolutely the same problem here, running the same from the command line and getting that exact same error.  I'll continue my research as well and post here if I find a solution, but please do post back if you find an answer!  Good luck!

Comment: do you guys have vaadin-client-compiler-{version}.jar in your classpath? Try replacing the path to com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.WidgetSetBuilder

Comment: Probles solved! just remove vaadin-client-compiler from classpath...